# How do I selectively install a package from a ppa?

Tags: apt, ppa

There is an updated package (coreutils) in a PPA that I am interested in installing on my server.  I added the PPA with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dns/gnu
```

In addition to coreutils, this PPA has a number other packages that I may not want to install.

Is there a way to configure apt such that only coreutils will get updated from this PPA?

Ubuntu 13.04 if that matters.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like exactly what I was looking for.  -- Bud